# HP Flexfabric MIB Reference ? (SNMP)

Tags: snmp, mib

Do you know where I can find a reference about SNMP Oids and MIBS for "HP Virtual COnnect FlexFabric module"? 
You can find a link to this product here: http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/blades/components/ethernet/10gb24/index.html

Even a reference for HP SAN Switchs (Not the brocade one) would be nice to start.
Seems I cant found it maybe you will have the answer before their support :)

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c03793980&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=4144084

From HP article above, it seems that you need to download the MIB Kit,

http://h18013.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/mibkit.html